# Efficient way of Using D3 to create hierarchical content from a CSV file

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have a list of tags in a CSV file with the second column showing which bundle they are a part of. Additional CSV rows with empty tag name indicates bundles.

I used [D3](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki) to read the CSV and generate a parent DIV for each bundle and populate the bundle DIVs with all tags listed within that bundle. I have a working example in this block: http://bl.ocks.org/anilsg/225acdf41638140959ae72aca039b815

I think my method is awkward. I have to delete nodes that are initially created at the wrong level and make a second pass on the data using a procedural approach.

Is there a better way of doing this? I noticed the D3 `key()` function and the `d3.hierarchy` module but I'm not sure if they're suitable candidates. Maybe there's a better way to use `filter()` and selections?

Comment: Apart from the lack of code in the question I'd consider this too broad for a good question on SO. Since your code is working and you are looking for a way to improve it, this might be a good question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. However, even there you are required to include at least the relevant parts of your code in the question itself.

Comment: @altocumulus were you not able to view the full working example that I linked? If practice requires I post and not link code please let me know. I guess I didn't really think of it as a code review because I'm so unfamiliar with D3 I'm looking for advice on how to implement in D3. This is just as far as I got.

Comment: @altocumulus, if it's you that demoted this question, please fix that. As you can see I have provided full code, and as you can see from the accepted answer, this is not about code review but about how to use D3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are two ways to deal with 'hierarchy' data structure in d3.js:** *d3.hierarchy*, *d3.stratify*

Using d3.hierarchy, your input data should be JSON format.
Using d3.stratify, your input data should be CSV or text and with only one root node.

---

**But** tag.txt you provided in the demo here, it can just use d3.nest() to make thing easier. Another concept you can pickup to modify your code for little better is the **Nested Selection** ([further reading](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) ) using selectAll and chaing data() leveraging the modifed data after transforming with d3.nest().

Beside, in your scenario, ***append*** and ***insert*** works the same. ***remove*** also not necessary, only if you need interactively updated.

**Here is the explanation of my code and little advices (opened for discussion)**

**First**, due to all your bundle elements are under container, so i just append it from body of html.

```
const container = bodyG.append('div')
                       .attr('id','container');
```

**Second**, we can begin to add first bundler elements on the container selection.

```
const bundles = container.selectAll('div.bundle')
                         .data(d3nest)
                         .enter()
                         .append('div')
                         .classed('bundle', true)
//d3nest is created by using d3.nest(), refer to the demo in the last line on Observable
```

**Third**, to make the code more clearly , I seperate the adding process of div text from defining bundle element.

```
bundles.insert('h2')
       .text((d)=> d.key);
```

**Fourth**, from here, we use the concept of Nested Selection by using SelectAll and data() to enter the nested data structure.

```
const tags = bundles.selectAll('p.tag')
               .data((d)=> d.values) // below here, all d mean d.values  
               .enter()              // which is the enter to the nest data.
               .append('p')
               .classed('tag', true)
               .text((d)=> d.tag);
```

Hoping this may provide some thoughts to you! It may not be the only way to make your original code better!

demo on Observable https://beta.observablehq.com/@weitinglin/is-there-a-better-way-to-use-d3-to-create-hierarchical-conten

Comment: D3 API reference for nest(): https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/master/README.md#nests

Comment: Thanks, using nest() is clearly on target and I have some pointers as to how to use select and data too. One thing I can't understand from your observable example is how you get the nested data out of the promise chain back up to the top level. When I implement your example in a web page I seem to be forced to process the data inside the promise for d3.csv https://github.com/anilsg/d3-tag-bundles

Comment: There are several difference between Observable environment and direct implementation in browser. In the browser, you need to consider the asynchronous behavior during web page rendering, which you dont need to worry about on Observable. d3.csv is a function based on d3.fetch, which you need to assign a callback function. Maybe you can wrap your code into a function to make more clean like d3.csv(''path", (error, data)=>{ render(data)})